# Show custom objects in UITableView row name

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to show my custom objects (images, formulas) in UITableView row name. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are lots of tutorials that show you how to do that.

[This](http://www.cocoacast.com/shownotes/Episode48.pdf) is my favorite. (PDF link). There is also [a video](http://www.cocoacast.com/?q=node/182) available.

Concept it pretty simple:

Just use a custom UITableViewCell and lay it out on Interface Builder.